# How do I change all functions in an array of objects without directly modifying them in any way?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects:

```
var cmds = [
  {
    ...,
    execute: function(args) {
      ...
    }
  },
  {
    ...,
    execute: function(args) {
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
];
```

I wanted to add the code for error checking using a function like:

```
function checkErrors() {
   ...
}
```

and stop execution of `execute` function if required.
I'd have simply added the `checkErrors()` function at the beginning of every `execute` and stop it based on its return value but there are a lot of different instances with `execute` and it is impractical to do this.
Also, wrapping `execute` with another function that calls `checkErrors` is not an option because it would mean I'd have to change the function name to something other than `execute` but it's been `call`ed at a lot of other places.

So, is there any way for me to do the above to check errors or perhaps other common initialization for every `execute` without changing each `execute` function itself?
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you have to change the function name if you wrap `execute` with another function?

Comment: @cherryblossom wrapping `execute` with another function would mean that the wrapping function's name would be something different and that will be the one that will be needed to be `call`ed instead of `execute`

Comment: Can’t you do `{execute: wrapFunction(function (args) {...})}`?

Comment: If you are worried about modifying the code directly, is it a problem to modify it with other code, indirectly? You can find every 'execute' and update it with other code at runtime to include your logic. This makes your code harder to read but you're not manually editing your execute functions.

Comment: @cherryblossom i'd have to change every `execute` which is kinda a pain. I was hoping for some solution to directly modify a preexisting function by adding some code towards it's start or end. Thanks for your help, though! I think I'll have someone manually add the code.

Comment: @JM-AGMS I guess I'm open to that. Though I don't have the time to write that code which does this. Do you know of any program which can help? Thanks!